# Mediawiki - what is the difference between If and #if?

Tags: mediawiki

What is the difference between a

```
{{If| ... }}
```

and

```
{{#if| ... |}}
```

in MediaWiki?

Which one should I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{{if|...}}` is a template, `{{#if:...}}` (mind the colon) is a parser function. The if template probably uses the if parser function internally, you can see that by going to Template:If on the wiki this is on. To learn more about the parser function, go to https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:ParserFunctions##if